# Custom repeating section in Cognito Forms

Tags: cognito-forms

I am working on creating a repeating section and I want to set "Number of Items" between 1 and then reference another number field for the top limit. So the top number would be variable to the number field. So far, using the advanced editor and reference the number field does not limit it.

Is this possible? And if yes, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Range limits, include repeating section quantity limits, can use calculations in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

The best way to show this is just to provide an example of a form where this is working.  Here is a link to a form where you can enter minimum and maximum limit amounts, which immediately apply as range limits on the repeating section.

**Form with calculated repeating section limits**
https://www.cognitoforms.com/ThomasFamily/RepeatingSectionLimits

**Shared template for this form**
https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/ThomasFamily/RepeatingSectionLimits

[image]